# Preimage of multiplication n-isogeny on a point of elliptic curve generates a Galois extension

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$ such that $E(K)$ contains all $n$-torsion points of $E$. Why is $K([n]^{-1}P)/K$ a Galois extension, for all points $P$? If the hypothesis that about $n$-torsion points is removed, is this still true?

Comment: You mean "for all points $P\in E(K)$"?  otherwise (without the $K$-rationality of $P$),  the  statement is false. (e.g., with $n=1$)

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant $P \in E(K)$. It also seemed to me like the $n$-torsion isn't needed, because if $\sigma \in Gal(\bar{K} / K)$, then since $\sigma$ commutes with $[n]$, it permutes the elements of $[n]^{-1}P$. This means every embedding of $L=K([n]^{-1}P)$ into $\bar{K}$ sends $L$ to itself, i.e., this is a normal extension hence Galois?

Comment: But in my lectures prof said it was needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your teacher meant that if $E(K)$ contains $E[n]$ and $Q$ is a point such that $[n]Q\in E(K)$ then $K(Q)/K$ is a Galois extension.

If $E(K)$ doesn't contain $E[n]$ and $S$ is **the set** of points $\{ Q\in E, [n]Q=P\}$ with $P\in E(K)$ then $K(S)/K$ is a Galois extension.

For the notation $[n]^{-1}P$: it is a well-defined element of the quotient group $E/E[n]$, so a set of elements of $E$.